# Ghostscript: When converting EPS to PNG, sometimes quality fails

Tags: resolution, ghostscript, eps

I am trying to convert some larger EPS images to PNG files using Ghostscript. I found a command, which normally does it quite well.

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dEPSCrop 
 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dTextAlphaBits=4
 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dUseCIEColor -r300x300 -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB
 -sOUTPUTFILE=outfile.png infile.eps
```

(all within one line, of course)

But I have some cases it just won't work properly.

E.g:

I have one eps image, Photoshop says it has **1977x3584px** at a resolution of **300dpi**.

Ghostscript produces png of only **474x860px** at **72dpi.**

What am I doing wrong. I see the height ratio 3584/860 is damn close to 300/72. But trying to adjust the resolution (-r) in my command line does not have any effect.

Another strange issue, which may be of interest:

My eps files contain a clipping path. Usually the command above will use it and add a transparent background to my png files.

Just in case resolution freaks out, there is no transparency.

I have not checked completely, but it seems that all eps files which make no problems, are only **72 dpi.**

If it matters, I use **GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08).**

Answer (score 1):

EPS files don't have a "resolution". EPS files are strictly prohibited (according to Adobe's spec)
from setting resolution or any other "device" parameters since they are intended to be "Encapsulated" into PS files. The program that encapsulates the EPS into the final image controls the position, scaling and resolution.

Without a sample file we can't tell much, but it with one, it is probably simple to diagnose.